# What's the idiomatic word for something that keeps you sane/grounded?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms, nouns

There's a word for something, that when remembered--or a person that when spoken to--brings you back to reality and the knowledge that you're not insane.  I keep wanting to say "touchstone", but I don't think that's it.  "Cornerstone" kind of works (and is probably why "touchstone" comes to mind), but is more about a foundation you build yourself upon, rather than something you come back to.

I think I'm looking for a synonym for reality check.  It's also the opposite of something that gaslights you.

Comment: A person or a belief can keep you "grounded". Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for the idiom that represents that person or belief.  Something akin to anchor.

Comment: People say, “She/He’s my ***rock***”

Comment: Hmm, not quite the word I'm looking for.  Rock is something you rely on constantly, something that supports you.  I'm thinking of something that you remember when you're experience doubt that reminds you of the truth/of reality with the sense of epiphany.

Comment: "Compass" might work, but I don't think it is widely used in the sense you're looking for.

Comment: Reason? I thought the whole world was against me. My reason prevailed and dispelled that notion.

Comment: Chocolate!!!!!!

Comment: SvenYargs That's probably the closest so far, but not the word I'm looking for. Like "rock", a compass is more of a guide to be constantly relied upon, rather than something that appears in a time of need. Zebrafish "Reason" is an internal entity while I'm searching for an external one. HotLicks bahahahaha! Thanks, everyone, for all you're suggestions!

Comment: It sounds like your talking about a *guardian angel*, a being (or something) that *only* appears when you are desperate. But your comments are slightly at odds with what you put into the question itself.

Comment: Something that helps you maintain your sanity should surely be called _sanitiser_. (Too bad it isn’t.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet /slowclap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, "touchstone" actually *was* the word I was looking for.  I just happened to be rereading the book from which I learned the word last night.

From [***The Wise Man's Fear***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wise_Man%27s_Fear) by Patrick Rothfus:

> Simmon gave a relieved smile and nodded encouragingly. “That’s it exactly. All your inhibitions have been sliced off so cleanly you can’t even tell they’re gone. But everything else is the same. You’re steady, articulate, and rational.”
>
> “You’re patronizing me,” I said, pointing at him with the knife. “Don’t.”
>
> He blinked. “Fair enough. Can you think of a solution to the problem?”
>
> “Of course. I need some sort of behavioral **touchstone**. You’re going to need to be my compass because you still have your filters in place.”

I took its definition from context, rather than the dictionary, so I was wrong about its meaning, but it was the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

An **anchor**:

> A person or thing that provides stability or confidence in an otherwise uncertain situation.
>
> ‘the European Community is the economic anchor of the New Europe’

[[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anchor)]

---

If you're comfortable with a movie reference, like "Gaslight" itself, I suggest "**totem**", as used in  the movie *Inception*:

> A Totem is an object that is used to **test if oneself is in one's own reality** (dream or non-dream) and not in another person's dream.

[[inception.wikia.com](http://nception.wikia.com)]

Comment: Totem is clever, but not the word I'm looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

> His **raison d'être**, his family's plight, when remembered brought
>   him back reality and sanity.

**raison d'être**. [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/raison+d%27etre)

> The fundamental reason for something or someone to exist; the sole or
>   most important purpose for someone or something.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be thinking of **lodestone**?

> [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lodestone)
>
> **Lodestone**: A person or thing that is the focus of attention or attraction.

Answer (score 0):

A number of idioms or expressions might work here. I might choose the idiomatic expressions ***the light in the dark*** or ***the beacon in the fog*** to refer to a person or belief that acts as a waypoint in navigating (such as sifting through what could be considered a web of lies).

Likewise, the idiomatic "location" you'd return to when checking in with your person or belief would be ***home***, or your ***center***, possibly your ***home base***. They act as a ***tether*** and as a ***ground*** for you.